# React creating a MixIn

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create a mixin for react. Using a simplified example - My goal is whenever an attribute/prop of `TOOLTIP` is found, it should add as child to that element my component of `React.createElement(Tooltip, {}, this.props.TOOLTIP)`

This hasnt been made clear on the official API page ( http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html ), or maybe I missed something, but is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using mixins as they can't have a render method. You need Higher Order Components for this.

Comment: This post is very informative - https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.tsy7tsqpw. It compares mixins with hoc and also has examples.

Comment: I read it but don't understand it :( Would you be able to show me how to write one with a tooltip? :( I saw react-tooltip but that relies on `browserify` and Im not allowed to use that :(

Comment: Sorry, but I am on the move right now. Been using the so app to post my responses. I will try to work on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for that thought I wll accept this just for the thought :) Please do follow up if you can I am a beginner at this :(

Comment: Appreciate the gesture. I personally prefer mixins over hoc because hoc pattern is very explicit. I would like to know few more things - is it acceptable to you if any component which uses your tooltip mixin invokes a method inside it's render? Another question I have is if you looked at the code of React tooltip? I like that it is very loosely coupled with consumer Components and doesn't alter their life cycle. You should be able to borrow it without the whole library.

Comment: Thanks Hazardous yes I checked it out, but I couldn't understand it, and it seems only usable via browserify. I asked author how to use without browserify but he said he doesnt know - https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/64  . But the tooltip thing is just so I can learn how to write the HOC. I thought it would be a simple learning lesson. Then I can move up to my main goal which is documented in a long outline haha. The explicitness would be nice so I could learn please :) ES5 style would be cool too as all i see out there is es6 which confuses me more haha

Comment: So you're not interested in a mixin based implementation, you would prefer doing this as a hoc?